# I want to extract the animation clip in FBX into a script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

I want to extract the animation clip in FBX into a script in Unity.

**I know how to extract animation clips from FBX with "ctrl+D".**

But what I want is to extract the animation clips from the FBX file into a **script**.

Can I script animation clips from FBX files while playing in Unity?

Please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApsVl.png)